# How to get duration of remote MP3 with minimum download

Tags: python, mp3

I am trying to get duration of 100,000 remote mp3 files. I don’t want to download each file as that could easily hit my data cap.

How could I get the duration of a mp3 file using python with minimum download size.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, MP3 files do not have a per-file header with a full length, but rather have a header for each frame. However, this isn't a huge issue for constant bitrate MP3s where you know both the length of a frame, and the length of the file (i.e. from an HTTP Content-Length header).

Assuming the file is constant bitrate, you should be able to download just the first 4 bytes of the file. This will give you the MPEG version/layer, as well as the bitrate (perform a table lookup against the MPEG specifications, documented [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190429042705/http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm)).

Knowing the bitrate, you can perform a rough estimate of the time based on the file length, or you may refine it by calculating the *actual* frame length in bytes. This gives you number of frames, and hence the number of bytes to subtract (since they are frame headers and contribute no useful data).

On the other hand, if you have a variable bitrate file, you're out of luck. You'll need to read every frame to obtain a true estimate of the file length.